How to use FFMPEG to convert mp4 to gif within a target file size?
I've seen many ffmpeg questions asking about compressing an mp4 to an mp4 but not to a gif.
I have an input.mp4 (12mb) that I would like to convert to output.gif whose result is 14mb using the normal conversion. I want it to be the best quality (both resolution and frame rate) under 10mb. How can I do that?
Something like ffmpeg -i input.mp4 --target-size=10mb output.gif?
I'm on Windows by the way.
